# plotting trajectories using matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Im trying to plot trajectories on matlab
My data file (try.txt) that has the trajectories looks like this:

```
NumofTrajectories

TrajID1 #ofPoints x y x y....

TrajID2 #ofPoints x y x y....
```

example:

```
7

0 23 898.6 673.0 859.1 669.9 813.7 667.8 776.8 664.0 739.8 662.1 699.9 654.7 664.5 649.6 625.3 645.5 588.2 640.6 552.3 634.2 516.6 628.2 477.2 624.3 442.1 613.6 406.7 603.4 369.5 599.8 332.7 594.1 297.4 585.2 258.6 583.7 224.1 573.1 191.2 556.8 152.7 554.0 115.1 546.0 79.6 535.8 

1 8 481.4 624.9 445.9 596.3 374.5 573.9 354.2 541.0 334.2 508.9 327.6 474.1 324.6 437.5 324.2 390.3 

2 24 151.6 570.8 188.3 556.5 225.1 547.7 257.9 529.4 292.9 509.8 326.8 496.8 356.2 476.0 391.2 463.3 423.7 447.9 455.7 431.8 489.2 416.0 524.3 405.3 560.0 395.9 595.8 385.6 632.8 376.1 671.5 372.0 706.9 361.8 742.3 347.3 778.0 334.5 820.5 336.5 856.5 325.0 894.5 309.5 946.1 309.9 990.5 287.0 

3 3 594.2 580.4 566.6 544.3 544.9 509.4 

4 5 281.8 661.9 266.8 623.4 246.2 576.4 229.7 541.0 220.9 498.4 

5 2 563.6 511.3 532.5 479.7 

6 5 571.9 617.7 525.6 576.4 481.0 551.9 456.8 524.2 419.7 474.0
```

I'm trying to plot this on matlab
my code is as follows:

```
clc;
clear;
%read the input
importfile('try.txt')

%See how many trajectorys there are convert to number
nTraj=str2num(cell2mat(textdata));

%loop over the trajectories
for i = 1:nTraj
        disp(data(i,1));
        %print the current trajectory number of points
        disp(data(i,2));

        %get the x-y coordinates of each trajectory
        current_traj=data(i,2);
        for j=1:current_traj
            points=data(i,3:j*2+2);    
        end
        %print the x-y coordinates of each trajectory
        %disp(points);

        %seperate the x-y coordinates of each trajectory
        x=points(1:2:length(points)-1)
        y=points(2:2:length(points))

        xlabel('latitude');
        ylabel('longitude');
        plot(x,y,'r');
        grid on ;
        hold on;
end
```

And function `importfile`:

```
function importfile(fileToRead1)
%IMPORTFILE(FILETOREAD1)
%  Imports data from the specified file
%  FILETOREAD1:  file to read

DELIMITER = ' ';
HEADERLINES = 1;

% Import the file
newData1 = importdata(fileToRead1, DELIMITER, HEADERLINES);

% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end
```

The code sometimes works and usually gives me an error say:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in ==> plotTrajectory at 23
            points=data(i,3:j*2+2);
```

Can someone explain the error and tell me how to fix it?

Comment: That is happening because the matrix `data` isn't as long as `j*2+2`. Try using debug mode by typing `dbstop if error` in the command line. Then the next time the error occurs, the script will freeze and allow you to examine the size of the data matrix and the value of j and you should be able to figure out what's wrong with the data or code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trajectories in `try.txt` have different lengths. `importdata` will use the first line to determine the length of your data. If another line is the longest, this line will be split over several lines of your imported matrix. At least this is what debugging shows. I would suggest you use another method to read your file. For me `dlmread` works:

```
%read the input
data = dlmread('try.txt', ' ');
% remove header
data = data(2:end,:);
%See how many trajectorys there are convert to number
nTraj=size(data,1);
```

You can replace your first lines with this code and remove your `importfile`function.

Comment: When I removed importdata and replaced it with dlmread it worked perfectly!